# How to change yaxis title position in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I'm trying to imitate this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HxDN.png) using pyplot and I've run into a problem.

I want my y axis title to be on top of y axis instead of middle.

Here's code for y axis and [current look of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjnGU.png) (arrow points into place where I want it to be)

```
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='grey', 
                 tickvals=[0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000],
                 title="NUMBER OF UNITS",
```

I can't find anything about this in documentation and will be grateful for any tips